Teenager picked up a radio signal from space that was trying to warn people of earth that the sun was going supernova
I remember watching a movie years ago about a teenager in Cali that picked up a radio signal from space that was trying to warn people of earth that the sun was going supernova. So he listened, he and others that listened to it lost their hair and turned grey and was able to go outside during and after the sun got brighter. It was a syfy movie but I can't remember the title and I have searched for many nights trying to find it.

When you say it was a syfy movie, do you mean that it was a science-fiction genre film or that it was a "Syfy original film" meaning the Syfy channel in the US?

I don't recall any US mainstream films set in Colombia.  Maybe you mean Cali as an abbreviation for California?

This is the Outer Limits episode Music of the Spheres, (1997).

Devon is later reviewing photographs taken of stars at different
  periods in time and discovers that the star of the alien world went
  ultraviolet 40 years in the past. He brings this information to his
  superiors and the military. They then realise that the radiation of
  Earth's sun is also changing to this spectrum, heralded by increased
  solar activity. Further research indicates that the noise/music is
  being transmitted to cause life on earth to mutate and transform so it
  can adapt to the new conditions, and that the alien transmission is in
  a sense a benevolent effort.
...
The final scene begins with Devon's father, still human, entering his
  daughter's room. She tells him that she is sorry that she won't be
  able to look beautiful in her prom dress, as the camera pans up
  showing her new skin to be a golden metallic substance.


Which episode was this?

Season 3, episode 14.
